# how to access method of a dynamically loaded user control vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a dynamically loaded user control and inside the user control I have a method that I want to call when I clicked the button on the form but it seems that it can't be recognized because it says " 'showTexboxMessage' is not a member of UControl1 "

Form1 code :

```
Dim UControl1 As New UserControl1
Private Sub applyLoan_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      PanelMain.Controls.Add(UControl1)
      UControl1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
      UControl1.Size = New Point(500, 533)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      UControl1.showTexboxMessage()
End Sub
```

in the user control, I had a textbox in it that I would want to display when the button in the form is clicked

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Sub showTexboxMessage()
       MessageBox.Show(textbox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Sub
```

the button has to be in the form and not in the user control. Hope you could help me.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new here so I didn't knew but the difference here and in my other post is that the other one is added at the panel and mainly about switching the displayed user control in the panel but maybe the title I put must look like it's the same so it's my fault then

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if I understand as well, but on the first code, try to change like this ↓

```
Dim ctrl1 As New UserControl1
```

Private Sub applyLoan_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
  PanelMain.Controls.Add(ctrl1)
  ctrl1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
  ctrl1.Size = New Point(500, 533)
```

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      ctrl1.showTexboxMessage()
End Sub

on the second code I dont understand what you want, coud u explain little better? cause if you want to show a message, it look like this ↓

```
Public Sub showTexboxMessage()
    MessageBox.Show("here is your message!!!")
End Sub
```

and if you want to show the textbox itself it look like that ↓

```
Public Sub showTexboxMessage()
    textbox1.visible = true
End Sub
```

obs* on the control where the textbox is, you should modify the property visible to false, cause the standard configuration is true ok

so anyway, good lucky :)

Comment: sorry my declaration of my user control seems wrong so I've edited it.. didn't noticed it until you point it out lol, in the second code, I want the text on the textbox in my user control to be displayed when the button in the form is clicked

Answer (score 0):

ok, if you want to show a text that is on another control you need to put the name of control before like this ↓

```
Public Sub showTexboxMessage()
    MessageBox.Show(formN.textbox1.Text)
End Sub
```

or if you refeer to you own control use the word **me** like that ↓

```
Public Sub showTexboxMessage()
    MessageBox.Show(me.textbox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Dont post two answers, why not modify your first one?

Comment: messagebox.show() and the textbox is in the user control so I didn't put the name of control and adding the "me" before doesn't change it anyways

Comment: So, lets go, u have a form1 for example and form2 or control or whatever....and you wanna take the text from textbox that is on the form2 for example and show it on a msgbox but on form1...?thats it?